# SPGroup - Get Child groups

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, spgroup

I am currently getting a list of groups a user is a member of using the following code:

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
var groupNames = (from SPGroup userGroup in user.Groups select userGroup.Name).ToList();
```

What I now need to do, is itterate through each SPGroup returning any child groups.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `SPGroup` cannot have children that are SPGroup. An `SPGroup` has chilren that are `SPUser`. But a `SPUser` can be a domain group (`IsDomainGroup` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.isdomaingroup.aspx). Which means that domain user and groups are kept as `SPUser` objects.